# How to validate XHTML with Xerces on commandline when w3.org stopped serving some files?

Tags: xhtml, xerces

I copied the example XHTML file from the [W3C recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/conformance.html):

```
$ cat > sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
              http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd"
>
  <head>
<title>Virtual Library</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<p>Moved to <a href="http://example.org/">example.org</a>.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The commandline tool `sax.Counter` does not work for the sample:

```
$ java -classpath /usr/share/java/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesSamples.jar sax.Counter -v -n -np -s -f sample.xml 
error: Parse error occurred - http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod
```

because one of the included file is missing:

```
$ wget http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod
--2018-10-22 23:08:30--  http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml-datatypes-1.mod
404 Not Found
2018-10-22 23:08:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I quit on Xerces and use xmllint instead.

xmllint works for the said sample.xml. First, you need to manually download [all](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11.xsd) [schema](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11-model-1.xsd) [files](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml11-modules-1.xsd) and save them in the same place you keep sample.xml.

Then use the main xsd file for validation:

```
$ xmllint --schema xhtml11.xsd sample.xml --noout
sample.xml validates
```

xmllint took 32 seconds to validate the sample.xml

Tested with the xmllint shipped with libxml 2.9.4 on Ubuntu as well as on the default xmllint on OS X Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following two lines in the sample

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

and Xerces will work. Using Java 11 and libxerces 2.11.0:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesSamples.jar
$ java sax.Counter -v -n -np -s -f sample.xml
sample.xml: 25176 ms (6 elems, 10 attrs, 0 spaces, 59 chars)
```

I am confused as of why the main `dtd` file is available but the component `mod` files are not. But at least w3 has kept the components of the `xsd` file online - until maybe one day they ditch it for some newer method to validate XML.